# strange shadows after removing doubles

Tags: modeling, error, shadows

I imported one voxel model from another program. When I tried to parent the armature, it showed error so I remove doubles from the model.
After removing doubles from the model, parent error was gone. But strange triangles appeared on my model. Shape of mesh didn't changed.
I searched the internet to fix this problem then recalculated normals, but nothing has changed.

[image]

This is how my model looks like after removing double.

---

[image]

This is my original model before removing double.

Answer (score 1):

You have *Smooth Shading* enabled. Select the object and switch to *Flat Shading* and it will look like before (*Object > Shade Flat*).

The other software split the connection between faces, similar to how Blender's *Edge Split* modifier works, to make the faces appear flat shaded. This is because the vertex normals are depending on the face normals of the neighboring faces. If the faces and edges are split from each other this doesn't happen, because there is only one face the vertex is part of. If you now interpolate the normals for the shading of the face, it will remain flat shaded even when you use Gouraud/Smooth shading.

A better approach that doesn't require the separation of faces and therefore duplication of vertices, is to simply not interpolate the face normals over the barycentric coordinates. That is what Blender's *Shade Flat* does.

[image]

Comment: It looks much better, but I can't still get rid of lines :(

Comment: What lines do you mean?

Comment: Strange shadows turned smaller, but it still appears after changing shading mode

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question that shows this problem?

Comment: Solved it! I don't know how but after deleting some edges and changing shading mode several times, now it looks well. Thanks !

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, then please mark it as accepted using the checkmark next to it. Thank you!